# plotly - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tools'

Tags: python-2.7, plotly

When I try to use plotly for Python 2.7 I get an AttributeError.

```
In [1]: import plotly
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c27a4132ad2e> in <module>()
----> 1 import plotly

c:\projects\flask\plotly.pyc in <module>()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tools'
```

So I tried this:

```
pip install tools
```

It gave me an error: `Failed building wheel for lxml`. So I just installed a .whl file

```
pip install lxml-3.6.0-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

After that I was able to install tools module. Yet, AttributeError is still there and won't let me use plotly.

Also, I tried using setting a virtual environment and use then plotly - I get the same error.

Comment: can you show how are you doing your import?

Comment: From the command line after running IPython

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it... All I had to do was to just delete plotly.pyc file in home directory. Not sure what it is for and how it got there, but it seemed out of place, so I deleted it and it worked!